# python extract keywords from multiple .gz files

Tags: python, gzip

Question: How to search keywords from multiple files in Python(including compressed gz file and uncompressed file)
I have multiple archived logs in a folder, the latest file is "messages",and the older logs will auto-compressed as .gz file.

- -rw------- 1 root root  21262610 Nov  4 11:20 messages
- -rw------- 1 root root   3047453 Nov  2 15:49 messages-20191102-1572680982.gz
- -rw------- 1 root root   3018032 Nov  3 04:43 messages-20191103-1572727394.gz
- -rw------- 1 root root   3026617 Nov  3 17:32 messages-20191103-1572773536.gz
- -rw------- 1 root root   3044692 Nov  4 06:17 messages-20191104-1572819469.gz

I wrote a function:

1. store all filenames in a list.(success)
2. open each file in the list, if it is gz file, use gzip.open().
3. search keywords

but I think this way is not very smart, because actually the message log is very big and it is separated into multiple gz files.And I have lots of keywords stored in a keywords file.

So is there a better solution to concatenate all files into a I/O stream and then extract keywords from the stream.

```py
def open_all_message_files(path):

    files_list=[]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.startswith("messages"):
                files_list.append(os.path.join(root,file))

    for x in files_list:
            if x.endswith('gz'):
                with gzip.open(x,"r") as f:
                    for line in f:
                        if b'keywords_1' in line:
                          print(line)
                        if b'keywords_2' in line:
                          print(line)
            else:
                with open(x,"r") as f:
                    for line in f:
                        if 'keywords_1' in line:
                            print(line)
                        if 'keywords_2' in line:
                            print(line)
```

Comment: I think this method is OK. You could only use `for word in list_of_keywords: if word in line:....` to make it shorter - and to work with different lists of keywords. Eventually I would save lines it database (splited to columns) to use `SQL` when I would need more complex rules to select lines.

Comment: I know you asked for a Python solution, but this command will do what you need in one line: `zgrep -f keywords **/messages*`

Comment: @chthonicdaemon thanks, that's what I'm doing now, but I have too many keywords to search, actually it is not simply searching, I'd like to write some functions to extract the timeline according to the keywords, so it is more complex task than just simply using linux commands.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first answer in stackoverflow, so please bear with me.
I had this very similar problem where I needed to analyze several logs, some of which were huge to fit entirely into memory.
A solution to this problem, is to create a data processing pipeline, similar to a unix/linux pipeline. The idea behind is to break each task to their own individual function and use generators to achieve a more memory efficient approach.

```
import os
import gzip
import re
import fnmatch

def find_files(pattern, path):
    """
    Here you can find all the filenames that match a specific pattern
    using shell wildcard pattern that way you avoid hardcoding
    the file pattern i.e 'messages'
    """
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            yield os.path.join(root, name)

def file_opener(filenames):
    """
    Open a sequence of filenames one at a time
    and make sure to close the file once we are done 
    scanning its content.
    """
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.gz'):
            f = gzip.open(filename, 'rt')
        else:
            f = open(filename, 'rt')
        yield f
        f.close()

def chain_generators(iterators):
    """
    Chain a sequence of iterators together
    """
    for it in iterators:
        # Look up yield from if you're unsure what it does
        yield from it

def grep(pattern, lines):
    """
    Look for a pattern in a line
    """
    pat = re.compile(pattern)
    for line in lines:
        if pat.search(line):
            yield line

# A simple way to use these functions together

logs = find_files('messages*', 'One/two/three')
files = file_opener(logs)
lines = chain_generators(files)
each_line = grep('keywords_1', lines)
for match in each_line:
    print(match)
```

Let me know if you have any questions in regards to my answer

Comment: Thanks! It solves my problems! I think It is a very pythonic and suitable to use generators, iterators and yield in such a situation. BTW we need to import fnmatch at the beginning. If I want to store all of the keywords in a file, I need to re-write the grep function to accept the list of patterns and then find all patterns right?

Comment: Nice solution. Consider using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) from the standard library rather than defining your own `chain_generators` though.

Comment: @will, yes you could modify the grep function to accept a list of patterns, however, to reduce runtime is better to look into regex documentation and figure out how you can look for multiple patterns in each line and avoid re.compiling each pattern.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon, the itertools.chain() function wouldn't work because it requires all of the chained iterables be specific arguments, which will cause the chain_generator() function to be fully consumed. Since that generator is producing a sequence of open files that are immediately closed in the next iteration step, chain() can't be use

Comment: @armrasec thanks! that's what I need to learn, the generator,iterators and regex

Comment: @armrasec just use `itertools.chain.from_iterables()` then.

Comment: @armrasec Hi, I have a question, what if I call the grep() function several times with different keywords, will "yield" give me the same location which was searched out at last time. How to set it to the default position.

Comment: @will, I will try to help you after I get out of work (k)

Comment: @will, from the top of my head, you could create a for loop with different patterns/keywords within the grep function.
    def grep(patterns, lines):
        """
        Look for a pattern in a line
        """
        for pattern in patter:
            pat = re.compile(pattern)
            for line in lines:
                if pat.search(line):
                    yield line