# How do i seek for "%d.txt" files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a lot of archives that are named as "1.txt", "2.txt" and so on. I'm trying to get ONLY this files.

I tried to use this, but it doesn't work.

```
path = r'c:\foo\foo'
dirs = os.listdir(path)
files = []

for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.txt' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

for f in files:
    with open(f, 'r') as text:
        fline = text.readlines()
        with open(f, 'r') as file:
            if '%d.txt' in f:
                print(f)
```

Comment: You can have a look at regular expressions to find files whose names match a given pattern.

Comment: `glob.glob('[0-9].txt')`. You may need a few more digit, but you can just concatenate the various glob calls, each with a different pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Regular Expression

in your example, you are comparing string '\d.txt' which will always return false

try this

```
import os
import re
path = r'C:\Roshan\stackoverflow\tr'
dirs = os.listdir(path)
files = []

for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.txt' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

for f in files:
    with open(f, 'r') as text:
        fline = text.readlines()
        with open(f, 'r') as file:
            if re.findall('\d\.txt',f):
                print(f)
```

Rememeber : Your code can be optimised by reading only the required files first and then reading the content. Its only a suggestion

Comment: When be simpler to use [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) since doing so wouldn't require using a regular expression.

Comment: Agree with you. glob.glob() is simpler and faster

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by roshan ok, you could use regular expressions.
Also, if you're interested in making your task general, that way in the future all you have to do is pass the pattern and path, you could look into this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58687367/12310699